# How to function from Controller in Model ROR3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hi i am new ruby on rails i need to know some basic information about 
how to call a function from controller to model

for ex:-
controller name : checkings

```
  def create
    @data = Checking.check()
  end
```

model name is Checking

```
  def check
    @a="xxxxx"
  end
```

how can i call from controller function to model function

Answer (score 0):

check is instance method,you have to make class method to call by class name,`def self.check end`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are referring to static function call. In ruby the static functions are defined with `self`.

```
def self.check
    a="xxxxx"
end
```

However, in rails, you should not populate instance variable in Model. In that case you can return the value from `check` function and assign it in controller function like

```
def self.check
    return "xxxxx"
end

#In controller
@data = Checking.check()  # "xxxxx" will be stored in @data
```

However, defining any function without `self` means its a instance function. So you need to call that function through any object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

We can call the model methods from controller using two formates,

1 . Creating singleton methods.
    Singleton methods are created using self keyword. example

```
  class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.check
    end
  end

  we can call this singleton method using following format,

  @checks = Check.check
```

2 . Creating instance methods.
      Instance methods are created using without self keyword

```
  class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
    def check
    end
  end

  we can call this singleton method using following format,

  @check =Check.new
  @checks = @check.check
```